# How do I get this list to render horizontally?

Tags: css, html

I have the following ul type list, and need to get it to display horizontally, but it doesn't. What am I missing?

```
<ul style="display: inline;">
    <li>
        <div class="store-display-item" style="display: inline;">
            <img class="store-display-image" src="/Images/ToughBook.jpg">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="store-display-item" style="display: inline-block;">
            <img class="store-display-image" src="/Images/ToughBook.jpg">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
li {
    float: left
}
```

need to float your li.

or you can use `display: inline-block;` on your li *doesn't work in IE7 and older*

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @ProfK thats why I added the 'or' :)

Answer (score 3):

Make your `<li>`-s inline - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4VwBY/)

```
<ul>
    <li style="display: inline;">
        <div class="store-display-item" style="display: inline;">
            <img class="store-display-image" src="/Images/ToughBook.jpg">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li style="display: inline;">
        <div class="store-display-item" style="display: inline-block;">
            <img class="store-display-image" src="/Images/ToughBook.jpg">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

Two things to make your code cleaner:

1. the `<div>` inside the `<li>` looks unnecessary - you can style the `<li>` to behave like a container
2. don't use inline CSS

**EXAMPLE**

```
<style>
li { display: inline; }
</style>

<ul>
    <li><img class="store-display-image" src="/Images/ToughBook.jpg"></li>
    <li><img class="store-display-image" src="/Images/ToughBook.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6Qj4/)

Comment: Duh! Thanks. Sorry, but @Mark answered a few seconds before you.

Comment: I think this is actually quite bad. You're suggesting placing block elements *inside* inline elements. **Edit** Just noticed you're setting the `div`s to `display: inline;`, which negates my comment, but still isn't fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: inline-block;`.

```
ul {font-size: 0;}
li {display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; *display: block; zoom: 1;}
```

Don't listen to people who say that `display: inline-block;` doesn't work in IE7. It does if you know what you're doing.